# Range addEventListner Input Updating too frequently

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript for context.
I want to have a web page where the user has a base number, which is an input and can have unlimited subtractors, or "sources", that will bring the number down. It's like the user is listing all of his or her sources to pay for something expensive. Each source will have a name and a range, which goes from -100 to 100.

The problem with it is that it takes every change in input as a potential source, but I want only the value of the ranges to be sourced. In other words, if the user has added five ranges, then I only want there to be five subtractors/sources.

Is there anything I could do to make this change happen? It also may be helpful to know that when I change the event listener to 'mouseDown' the same thing happens.

Here is everything I have written.

```js
const addBtn = document.querySelector(".solvePlusLogo")

function addSolvr() {
    solvContain = document.querySelector('.solveContainer')
    const solvDiv= document.createElement('div');
    solvContain.appendChild(solvDiv);
    const solvLabel = document.createElement('input');
    solvDiv.appendChild(solvLabel);
    const solvRange = document.createElement('input');
    solvRange.type = "range";
    solvRange.className = "range"
    solvDiv.appendChild(solvRange);
}
addBtn.addEventListener('click', addSolvr)

let full = document.querySelector("#numInput").value

document.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  if(event.target.matches(".range")) {
    const subtractors = []
    subtractors.push(event.target.value)
    for(let x of subtractors) {
      full -= x
    }
    document.querySelector("#numDisplay").innerHTML = full
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="number" id="numInput">
    <h3 id="numDisplay">
      $0
    </h3>
    <div class="solveContainer" style="font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', momnospace;">
      <div class="solveIntro">
          <button class="solvePlusLogo">Add Source
              <a href="#bottom"></a>
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use the `change` event rather than `input`. It will only be triggered when the user releases the mouse.

Comment: @Barmar the same thing happens. It stacks each input on top of another, regardless if it's coming from the same range input.

Comment: You need to set `full` inside the event listener. Otherwise you're subtracting the current value of the range from a previous value was already subtracted.

Comment: @Barmar would `full` be the first argument?

Comment: No. Just move the line `let full = document.querySelector("#numInput").value` inside the event listener.

Comment: @Barmar Oh that works great! Only thing is that now the range inputs aren't adding up when displaying. It's only taking data from one range at a time.

Comment: I've posted an answer, it solves that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time the range changes, you're subtracting its current value from `full`. But `full` has previously had a different range value subtracting, so these subtractions are accumulating.

You need to get the current value of `#numInput` and subtract the range value from it.

Your `subtractors` array will just contain the value of the current range input. You need to loop over all the ranges and combine them.

```js
const addBtn = document.querySelector(".solvePlusLogo")

function addSolvr() {
  solvContain = document.querySelector('.solveContainer')
  const solvDiv = document.createElement('div');
  solvContain.appendChild(solvDiv);
  const solvLabel = document.createElement('input');
  solvDiv.appendChild(solvLabel);
  const solvRange = document.createElement('input');
  solvRange.type = "range";
  solvRange.className = "range"
  solvDiv.appendChild(solvRange);
}
addBtn.addEventListener('click', addSolvr)


document.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  if (event.target.matches(".range")) {
    let full = document.querySelector("#numInput").value

    const subtractors = document.querySelectorAll(".range");
    subtractors.forEach(subtractor => full -= subtractor.value)
    document.querySelector("#numDisplay").innerHTML = full
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <input type="number" id="numInput">
  <h3 id="numDisplay">
    $0
  </h3>
  <div class="solveContainer" style="font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', momnospace;">
    <div class="solveIntro">
      <button class="solvePlusLogo">Add Source
              <a href="#bottom"></a>
          </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```